# When complex state is updated by useReducer, where should an API call be made?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using React's useReducer, I have a complex state that is updated according to a number of conditions. When the state updates, I want to log the state change to a database - but should not put API calls within the useReducer, as it should be a pure function.

What is the best practice in this situation? I can use a `useEffect`, but I want to avoid having to duplicate all the reducer logic for the API call.

A subset of my state could be:

```
    users: [{
        name: "Bob", 
        accounts: [
          {type: "Savings", balance: 24},
          {type: "Credit",  balance: 15}],
        address: "34 Rosendale Avenue"
      },
      // ...
    ]
```

A subset of my reducer looks like this:

```
  function reducer(oldState, action) {
    let state = structuredClone(oldState);
    switch (action.type) {
      case "bonus_added":
        state.users.forEach((user) => {
          user.accounts.forEach((account) => {
            if (account.type === "Savings") {
              account.balance += 10;
              // Would like to also make API call here to log this change
            }
          });
        });
        return state;
      default:
        throw Error("Unknown action.");
    }
  }
```

There is a working example in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-agnesi-t6t7pm).

**UPDATE**

Using `useState` I can create an approach that looks and behaves like `useReducer`, without using `useReducer`:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);
```

is very similar to (see this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wozniak-lfqqtm)):

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initState);
const dispatch = (action) => setState(reducer(state, action));
```

As far as I know, there is no requirement for functions that use `useState` to be pure - so in the second case, my reducer function could include an API call.

Is this a sensible approach?

Comment: It's not clear to me: If you **(A)** want to log the whole state, then you wouldn't have to duplicate any reducer logic in the useEffect, you'd just use the current state. If you instead **(B)** only want to log a part of the state, you wouldn't duplicate reducer logic either, because you'd want a different result. - what should it be ? -- One option would be to have kind of "action caller" functions, which log something _before_ the dispatch is invoked.

Comment: @kca I want to make an API call relating to the part of the state that has changed, so *(B)*. So in this instance, I want to make an API call to log the updated balances of the modified accounts. If doing this outside of the reducer, I would need to recreate both `forEach` loops and the `if` statement to see which accounts need updating.

Alternatively I could create a new part of the state (`state.accountsToUpdate`) that the reducer writes to, for a useEffect to inform which API calls to make - and then have another reducer action that clears that state.

Either approach seems painful!

Comment: @pancake you can create a callback e.g `balanceChanged(account)` which calls the appropriate API, and call the callback everytime balance is changed. Or, you could also wrap the balance changing operation and its logger in a method and calls it everytime you want to change the balance.

Comment: @pancake I understand now. Interesting. I also thought about your idea, creating an own `useReducerWithSideEffects`. I feel like that works fine and is a reasonable way to fix you problem at hand, but still bypasses the idea of reducers. I guess [`redux` and their tools](https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches) do something similar, don't know. -- I might write an answer about the _conceptual_ problem, when I'm sure enough about it. E.g. the dispatch and the log "say" different things: "add bonus" vs. "log the bonus of user x, account y".

Comment: As a side note: Be aware that `structuredClone` will un-necessarily create new references for all nested objects. I.e. any sub-components that only display a part of the nested state would always re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer** *(if you need to stick with your requirement regarding the log)*:

You *(probably)* need to build the new state ***before* the reducer is called**,

- either partially by duplicating logic,
- or by replacing the whole state.

You may modify the data structure, to access values more efficiently.

You can use **libraries** that add ways to use side effects on state updates
(like [`redux` and their other tools](https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches), I believe [redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware) does that ?).

Using such libraries might be a reasonable approach, but IMO is usually **mis-used to circumvent React principles**, and even negate the whole idea and value of using React.

I suspect that you should **revise your requirements**, especially if that specific log is really the best approach (See details further below).

### Your options, based on the given requirements

- The new state is determined inside the reducer. Therefore, the information about **the new state** is not available earlier (e.g. inside the action dispatcher).
- The information about **the fact that this specific value *will* change** is available inside the event handler / action dispatcher.
- The information about **the fact that *something* changed** is available when using a `useEffect`,
- The information about **the change of that value** is not available at all *(as it is now)*.

Given that you should not add side effects to the reducer, there are only two options:

1. build the new state **before** the reducer is called,
   e.g. inside the action dispatcher (possibly duplicating logic), or
2. query the state **after** the reducer is done,
   with a `useEffect`, storing the previous state somewhere and compare it with the new state.

I'd prefer option 1., where again you can choose a "grade of abstraction", e.g.

- completely **duplicate** the whole logic
  (i.e. traverse the state inside the action dispatcher and again inside the reducer), or
- build the state separately, and completely **overwrite** the whole state
  (effectively building your own reducer).
- or anything in between,
  e.g. build and dispatch some part of the new state.

As said before, you can use some **library**, which probably does something similar as suggested here
*(e.g. intercepting the dispatch, execute some intermediate logic, call the final reducer with a modified state / dispatch / reducer)*.

#### - Example: Intercept a specific dispatch before it reaches the reducer

```
const useInterceptedReducer = function( originalReducer, initialState = {} ){

    const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer( originalReducer, initialState );

    const interceptedDispatch = function( action, beforeDispatch ){

        // -- internal "reducer", with side effects
        switch( action.type ){

            // -- intercepted actions:
            case 'bonus_added':
                // const newState = originalReducer( state ); // you could also call the real reducer here 
                const newState = beforeDispatch( state );
                dispatch({ type: 'replace_state', payload: newState });

            // -- all other actions:
            default:
                dispatch( action );
        }
    };

    return [ state, interceptedDispatch ];
};

...

const beforeDispatch = ( state ) => {
    // build state, and do side effects 
    return state;
};
 
...

dispatch({ type: 'bonus_added' }, beforeDispatch );
```

#### - Example: Write your own "reducer" with side effects

```
const useReducerWithSideEffects = function( reducer, initialState = {} ){
    const [ state, setState ] = useState( initialState );

    const dispatch = function( action ){
        const newState = reducerWithSideEffects( state, action );
        setState( newState );
    };

    return [ state, dispatch ];
};
```

### Why you are facing these problems

The contradiction lies in the combination of:

1. the choice of the technology (React),
2. the state structure (e.g. a simple tree, without IDs),
3. the requirement to access one specific value inside the state

Ideally you would **choose the technology** and state structure **based on your requirements**.
I assume what happened instead is that you choose the technology, and "found" additional requirements later.

#### 1. / 3.: React vs. arbitrary side effects

React is supposed to be used mainly to

- transform state by creating a new state as *a function of a previous state*
- display a UI as *a function of the current state*

In React you can also

- query the state,
- define the transform function,
- trigger a transformation,
- execute side effects base on the current state.

But you are *not supposed to* execute side effects based on specific transformation logic.

#### 2.: The state structure

The tree structure is ok, as long as you don't have to access specific deeply nested
values efficiently.

Otherwise, you should at least add IDs (e.g. `users: [ { id: 123, ... }, ... ]` ), or even use an object with keys (or a `Map`).
E.g. your state might be structured roughly like this:

```
users: {
  user_123: { savings_account: { ... }, ... },
  user_124: { savings_account: { ... }, ... },
  ...
}
```

that way you could efficiently access the value with `users['user_123']['savings_account']`.

*(I don't suggest this, I only want to illustrate that the state could be designed in many different ways, based on the requirements.)*

### Suggestions to think differently

Your requirements might be justified in this case. I have no way of knowing, without background information about the purpose of your log,
but here are some suggestions to maybe think in a different direction.

#### Single source of truth

Generally it is advisable to maintain one [Single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).

Your log will send a state to an external database, while "at the same time" the same state is stored inside the
local state.

API requests can fail or be delayed, or might be sent in the wrong order. So there is no guarantee anyway that
your log would represent the local state.

A solution could be to maintain the whole state inside the external database,
where your log can probably be updated at the same time, together with the "add bonus" - request.

#### Imagine an external database

If you imagine your data would be stored in some external, possibly large database, you might come to conclusions how you could arrange your
state differently.

E.g. you would update the state via SQL, like

```
UPDATE myState SET savingsAccout = savingsAccout + 1 WHERE userId = 123
```

and you would never ask how you can log the updated `savingsAccout` value inside this request.

It would be obvious that you can only log it **before updating the DB**, or **query the new value later**, even
without any guarantee that it is really your just updated value *(it might be delayed or updated from somewhere else)*.

#### What do you really want to analyze ?

Do you really need the information about *when* exactly *which* value has changed to *which* new value ?
Maybe you do, but think about what you really want to know **at the very end**.

E.g. if you want to create some statistics about how much bonuses were granted, can't you store that information directly in your state ? Like:

```
if (account.type === "Savings") {
  account.balance += 10;
  user.bonusesGranted += 10;
}
```

Then you can query that information later, when you actually want to analyze it.

Probably you need the `bonusesGranted` information in your external database, so ...

#### ... where should the state live ?

Are you sure that every part of the state is stored at the optimal place ?

Maybe you can move your local state into the database, or some database state into the local state.

#### Consider the level of abstraction

Consider how your action and the log are related.

Generally you would design your actions according to what is relevant for your **current point of view**.
Details get intentionally abstracted away, so they are not available anymore.

I.e. you can easily log the dispatched action, you can not (easily) log information you have abstracted away.

For example:

Your action says to the reducer *"add a bonus everywhere, you'll sort it out"*. Note that this statement doesn't include a specific user, account or value.

As it is, you could easily log `'a bonus will be added'`, but you can't (easily) log the specific user, account and value.

The other way around, you could change your action to *"add a bonus of 10 for user id 123"* (i.e. `{ type: 'bonus_added', payload: { userId: 123, value: 10 } }`),
then you could log the value, but you also would need to dispatch a separate action for each user (and add user-ids).

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a well-considered and detailed answer - I really appreciate it. You're right: ultimately the state is stored in an external database, and that needs to be the single source of truth. However, the app needs to be very interactive (in the way that Excel or Google Sheets is) so would be a bad user experience to wait for a database round trip before updating the UI. I use optimistic UI updates and correct if necessary - hence needing to change the UI state and make an API call.

Comment: I also agree that my problem in some way stems from not using the most appropriate technology for this particular use case, although 90% of my app is in the browser where React works really well for the UI state - and need to robustly link in my API calls. It seems `useReducer` is not really suited to my needs, so either intercepting or writing my own reducer with side effects as you suggest may be the best compromise.

I think if starting again I may just not use React (or any UI framework) as trying to fit a square peg into a round hole is hard!

Comment: Thanks again - unfortunately my bounty expired, so it's too late to award it to you!

Comment: Don't worry, I was aware of the bounty being expired :) -- Using React is definitively a tradeoff, but usually worth it, even to deal with the "restrictions", IMO... But aren't there always tradeoffs ? :) Some very specific Web-Apps even don't use the browser-DOM at all, but instead just create one big canvas, and implement a complete custom UI.

Answer (score 1):

Reducers are not supposed to have any side effects, hence I would not recommend making the API call from within the reducer.

Instead, I would suggest that you make the API calls from the same level you make the reducer dispatch.

For example:

```
function addBonus() {
  dispatch({type:"bonus_added"})
  logBonusesAdded() //Make API calls
}
```

### Edit

As pointed out by @kca, `logBonusesAdded()` would have to duplicate logic from the reducer.

To prevent that I would consider simplifying the reducer to only operate on single objects and move logic out of the reducer.

I would also recommend making your state immutable, e.g. design your reducer functions in a way that they always return immutable data structures.

Furthermore, I wouldn't update the UI until the change is reflected in your database. Hence, make `logBonusAdded` return a promise and call the reducer dispatch when the promise resolves.

Like this:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "bonus_added":
      return {
         ...state,
         users: state.users.map((user) => {
            if(user.id === action.payload.id) {
                return {
                    ...user,
                    account: {
                        ...user.account,
                        balance: user.account.balance + action.payload.amount
                    }
                }
            }
            return user
         })
      };
    default:
      throw Error("Unknown action.");
  }
}
```

```
function addBonuses() {
   const amount = 10;
   state.users.forEach((user) => {
      user.accounts.forEach((account) => {
        if (account.type === "Savings") {
           logBonusAdded(account.id, amount).then(()=>{
               dispatch({type:"bonus_added", payload: {id: account.id, amount});
           });   
        }
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: This would _generally_ also be my suggestion, but `logBonusesAdded()` will still have to duplicate the logic to find the "Savings" accounts (and the value, as I understood it).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @kca. I've updated my answer with a more in depth suggestion, taking code duplication into consideration.

Comment: Thanks @EmilJ. This is *a* solution, but it still creating a lot of extra logic with two distinct functions having to know about the process of adding the bonus. I'm coming to the conclusion that there isn't a great solution with `useReducer`.

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you with this https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usereducer-middleware/

or you can do this
[image]

Comment: Thanks @RegOgbemudia, that's a useful link and I think this is the best solution out of those proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Could be custom events are a little more elaborated but I think it works very well.

For example:

```js
  const makeApiCall = async (event) => {
    // make the api call and additional stuff here
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log(event.detail);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // add a window eventlister
    window.addEventListener("callApi", makeApiCall);

    return () => {
      // remove it on cleanup
      window.removeEventListener("callApi", makeApiCall);
    };
  }, []);

  function reducer(oldState, action) {
    let state = structuredClone(oldState);
    switch (action.type) {
      case "bonus_added":
        state.users.forEach((user) => {
          user.accounts.forEach((account) => {
            if (account.type === "Savings") {
              account.balance += 10;
              // dispatch a CustomEvent that allows any data to be passed through the detail property
              window.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent("callApi", { detail: account })
              );
            }
          });
        });
        return state;
      default:
        throw Error("Unknown action.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: `window.dispatchEvent` is still a side effect inside the reducer. Apart from that: What is won with this approach, related to the direct api request ?

Comment: Thanks @alvaro, but as kca states this isn't a pure reducer, so doesn't achieve the goal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to do this! usually when we work with database and application data, we want to keep them in sync, makes sense, but updates inside the database should always happen first and then follow the changes from the app.
 here in your example you may lose synchronization when the API fails because you are updating the state before calling it.

what I would do is create an endpoint for that task, move your logic there and after updating the database you return an array with the updated accounts ids as response.

from your React app, you just call the endpoint when you have to, and if that succeeds, you pass the response data (i.e. the array) to your reducer function to track updates in your state .

```js
function reducer(oldState, action) {
  const updatedAccounts = action.payload;
  let state = structuredClone(oldState);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "bonus_added":
      updatedAccounts.forEach((id) => {
        state.users.find((user) => user.id === id).account.balance += 10;
      });
      return state;
    default:
      throw Error("Unknown action.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hatana. My app needs to be very responsive so I'm making optimistic state updates that are reflected instantaneously in the UI, then a database update is made, and the UI will later correct if the database becomes inconsistent. E.g. when you're dragging a cell in Google sheets, the UI updates as the mouse moves, and the database update happens in the background.

The best solution I have for now is to create a to-do list for the API calls as part of the state which is managed by the reducer, with a `useEffect` on that to-do list; when the to-do list changes, the API call is made.

Comment: I know there are some alternatives as the one you mentioned but when you make a request it is ok to wait for the response to update your state it is in fact the best practice. With your approach here you update the state then you make the API call once the state is updated and if the API fails for some reason maybe the server is down then what do you do? update your state again to the old previous value? does not make sense to me.